# Two divs opacity difference

Tags: jquery, css

Basicly i'm trying to create image cropping script, and it's almost done, here is my script:

http://jsfiddle.net/7C8fp/3/

But i can't figure out how to make `crop_area` to have clear background without that dark color, can any one be so kind and help me out a bit? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create 5 divs to do that - impossible with just one - unless you used `canvas` element on which you'd cut out the square representing the selected area.

```
    [////////////]
    [//][    ][//]
    [////////////]
```

something like that :)

and then as you change the size / position of selected area you need to recalculate all the positions of the divs to match the target region for cropping

Comment: well that seems to be a bit hard, but i guess there is no other choise

Comment: it's very easy - you already have the top left and bottom right corner positions so it's silly easy to calculate the positions /widths for each container - you told in a comment below that you want to do it for a challenge and i think it's a fun case to play with :) if you were stack ping me on this comment with what you are struggling with

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're doing this for the challenge or fun of it, why not consider using a library such as Jcrop: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php

Comment: im doing it for the challenge, since this is quite hard and fun at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible while adding the same pic in the background of the crop_area.

I've made it here : http://jsfiddle.net/7C8fp/10/

```
//---------container--------//

//get image width and height
var width = $("#container img").width();
var height = $("#container img").height();

//set css to container
$("#container, #black_bg").css({width: width, height: height});

function bgUpdate()
{    
    area=$( "#crop_area" ); 
    bg=area.position();
    bgLeft=width-bg.left
    bgTop=height-bg.top;
    area.css({'background-position':bgLeft+'px '+bgTop+'px '});
}

//--------crop area-------//
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#crop_area" ).css({
    left: width / 2 - 60,
    top: height / 2 - 80,
}).resizable({
    aspectRatio: 9 / 10,
    containment: "#container",
    handles: 'n, e, s, w'
}).bind('resize', function(){bgUpdate();});

bgUpdate(); 

$( "#crop_area" ).draggable({containment: 'parent'}).bind('drag', function(){bgUpdate();});                                                          
});
```

And in your CSS

```
#crop_area{width:120px; height:160px;  position:absolute; 
background:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Ly7zNPYNc4c/TmDqZ9yF4FI/AAAAAAAAAnc/EqOw62ryF5w/s1600/Anime-Wallpapers-5.jpg);
background-size:466px 350px;
}
```

It could be optimized, and there is some cliping, but it works (lol)

Edit : changing live() for bind() makes work the bgUpdate with resize
http://jsfiddle.net/7C8fp/11/

Comment: but it's quite laggy, i'm trying to make what Tom Tu sugguested, i thing that would work faster

Comment: oh sorry... resize is ok, drag lags, have to be optimized it, but if you have the solution I won't do it...

Comment: thank you for your help, but i already did it here how it looks
http://jsfiddle.net/7C8fp/12/ still few bugs left but there isn't so much lag :)